# finding the top 5 geographical locations in a database

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude, location-services

I am trying to write a program that has the ability to search through an sqlite database of different sites that have their geographical coordinates and i need to be able to return the closes five coordinates to the users current position, I already have used reverse-geocoding to find my current position and the distance from the sites, however I have not been able to display the closest five. Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: How accurate do you need to be? To get it 100% right every time, there's a lot of math involved. If there's enough distance between your stored locations that you can afford to be a little "fuzzy" with the relative distances, you can probably get away with some simple arithmetic.

Comment: It has to be somewhat accurate because there are sites that are all around the united states and even just being off by .001 could be a completely different site, it is a database of of 60,000 sites around the U.S.

Comment: Are you using [SpatiaLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpatiaLite) with your database?

Comment: No I am not, would that make this task easier if I add that on to the database?

Comment: If you're doing a lot of geospatial work (including distance calculations) with your data, then yes, it probably would be to your advantage to use it (try it on a test copy of your database and find out for yourself). I haven't used it myself, but have used the geospatial features of another RDBMS and it beats writing my own code to do the calculations.